# Display Author Name, Book Name for those authors who wrote more than one book

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Book_Master(
Book_code NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Book_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
Book_pub_year NUMBER,
Book_pub_author VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000001,'Let Us C++',2000,'Yashavant Kanetkar');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000002,'Mastersing VC++',2005,'P.J Allen');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000003,'JAVA Complete Reference',2004,'H.Schild');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000004,'J2EE Complete Reference',2000,'H. Schild');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000005,'Relational DBMS',2000,'B.C. Desai');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000006,'Let Us C',2000, 'Yashavant Kanetkar');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000007,'Intoduction To Algorithams',2001,'Cormen');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000008,'Computer Networks',2000,'Tanenbaum');

INSERT INTO book_master VALUES(10000009,'Introduction to O/S',2001,'Millan');
```

Comment: Take your homeworks seriously. Show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point for the logic is to determine multiple distinct Books versus grouping by authors. This way, one option would be containing `in` operator :

```
select Book_pub_author, Book_name 
  from book_master 
 where Book_pub_author in ( select Book_pub_author 
                              from book_master 
                             group by Book_pub_author 
                            having count(distinct Book_name)>1 )
 order by Book_pub_author, Book_name;
```

and another more elegant way would be joining that subquery with the table as :

```
 select b1.Book_pub_author, b1.Book_name  
   from book_master b1
   join (  select Book_pub_author
             from book_master
            group by Book_pub_author
           having count(distinct Book_name) > 1 ) b2
     on b1.Book_pub_author = b2.Book_pub_author
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b123761497700270e4251a2758e4c5a0)</kbd>

Comment: Thx for your help

Comment: @AbhiramVarma you're welcome.